# Returning a C-array in cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to write a simple cython function which takes a size and initial value of a 2D array. It only sets the first row and then returns the array. However it doesn't work and it raises `Cannot convert 'double **' to Python object`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
cdef ccsolve_eq(int size,double *init_vals):
    cdef double** frozen_ans= <double**> malloc(size*sizeof(double))
    frozen_ans[0]=<double*> malloc(dim*sizeof(double))
    return frozen_ans
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the return value:

```
cdef double** ccsolve_eq...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what happens when you forget everything of what you know about C/C++!